# GA Reporting API returns 0 ga:users when range starts before 2016-08-23

Tags: google-analytics-api

Using the Analytics Reporting API, I request the total number of visitors (`ga:users`) between `2016-05-23` and yesterday (`2019-05-02`):

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-08-23&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Ausers

```
ga:users => 1,373,311
```

But if I start the range one day before, I get a completely different result. When grouping by month, I can see I get 0 visitors every month except the current one:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-08-22&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Ausers

```
ga:users => 2,931
```

I've tried to request only a couple of months starting from Aug 22, 2016, I get the same issue (0 visitors every month). But it's fine if I start the range on Aug 23, 2016. There's something wrong when you go before that date.

I've tried on 2 different accounts and had the same problem for the same date.

Also same issue using the [Ruby API](https://github.com/tpitale/legato) instead of the query explorer.

But the data is fine in Analytics itself. It's only a problem with the API.

Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: I just faced an issue with the same date - 2016-08-23. If I include this date into request, I get zeros for all days. Did you figure out this issue?

Comment: Nope. I stopped requesting data that far back with the API. In my use case, having 2 years of history was enough.